# Why is the category of modules over a ringed space a Grothendieck category?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ct.category-theory

If $(X,\mathcal A)$ is a ringed space, I see at several places in the literature that the category of sheaves of $\mathcal A$-modules must be a Grothendieck category. Is there a reference to an actual proof of this? I am sorry if this question is too easy.

Comment: Tôhoku? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck's_T%C3%B4hoku_paper

Comment: @David: Of course, Proposition 3.1.1 in Grothendieck's Tohoku paper says that this is true, but I would not consider what is said there to be an "actual proof" as requested by the OP.

Answer (score 4):

This is Theorem 18.1.6 of *Categories and sheaves* by Kashiwara and Schapira (Springer, 2006).